# Cant get the zend loader to load classes only under wamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-loader

I'm trying out the zend framework classes for the first time. I am interested in using some of the individual classes for now.
Reading the documentation and some other q's here and in blogs I've tried three ways to load the classes

```
    //attempt 1 - using zend loader
require_once('library\Zend\Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Date');

    //attempt 2 - direct class load
require_once('library\Zend\Date.php');

    // attempt 3 - auto load
set_include_path('D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Loader\Autoloader.php';


$date = new Zend_Date();

// Output of the desired date
print $date->get();
```

my folder structure is:

- zend_test(folder) 
  -- testLoad.php (the above code lives there) 
  -- library(folder) 
  --- zend(doler) 
  ---- (the zend libs and sub folders)

I get the following error messages:
**attempt 1**

```
Warning: include(Zend\Date.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend\Date.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 83

Warning: require_once(Zend/Exception.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 87

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Exception.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 87
```

**attempt2**

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Date/DateObject.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Date.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Date/DateObject.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Date.php on line 25
```

**atempt3**

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php on line 24
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend;.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php on line 24
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your include path should read:

```
include_path='D:\wamp\www\testPages\zend_test\library;.;C:\php5\pear
```

When it tries to load the class Zend_Date it looks for a folder called Zend in the include path, with a file called Date.php in it.

All 3 of your methods should work with this corrected, and I recommend attempt 3.

Answer (score 1):

used method 3 and did this to get it working:

```
set_include_path('D:/wamp/www/zendTest/library/');   
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Date'); //or whatever zen class
```

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini remove ";" before line include_Path and restart your wamp!